# Difference between maxPageSize and Prefetch limit in activemq

Tags: activemq-classic

Can anyone please tell me the difference between maxPageSize and prefetch limit?

Answer (score 2):

maxPageSize: according to apache websitemaximum number of persistent messages to page from store at a time. This is when messages are stored in persistent store (like kahadb). You have reference of the message stored in the database. This maxPageSize limits the number of references for message you can have. You have this reference for faster access from database (like having an index in database which increase the performmance)

Prefetch Limit: is related to sending number of message to consumer to improve performance. If you set prefetch limit as 0, means consumer would keep on polling for message from queue however if you set it as 100 then activemq would send 100 message in advance (prefetched to consumer) to consumer to process which would remove an extra effort which otherwise would have to make by consumer to check for any message on queue.